# Why lock in Testdatabase but not in Devdatabase

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, locking

I have just setup a testing clone of the database we use for development. However, when I run our application against this new database it creates a lock and in the end timeout waiting forever.

The SQL that creates my problem:

```
-- In one connection it runs this
set transaction isolation level read committed
begin tran
INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[Status] ([TransactionID], [Status]) VALUES (6122481, 1)
```

Then before that transaction is committed another connection tries to run:

```
set transaction isolation level read committed
begin tran
SELECT * FROM [Test].[dbo].[Status] with(rowlock) WHERE [Test].[dbo].[Status].[TransactionID] = 6122482
```

However, this second transaction will never run as it waits for the first one to complete forever until the application timeouts.

1. SQL Server 2008
2. I have not much control over the actual SQL, we use LLBLGen (ORM) for it
3. It works fine on our development and production databases.
4. The test database was created by restore of a new backup of the dev database
5. I think the major difference is the number of rows in the table (<100 in test compared to > 100000 for dev)

My guess is that SQL server does things differently when there's a lot of rows in the table. Question is how to fix the test database without adding lots and lots of data to it if thats the problem, or what else I should do?

The table has some indexes, and also a FK on the transaction table on TransactionID:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx1] ON [dbo].[Status] 
(   [TransactionID] ASC,
    [Status] ASC
) INCLUDE ( [Created]) 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx2] ON [dbo].[Status] 
(   [Status] ASC,
    [Created] ASC
) INCLUDE ( [TransactionID]) 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Status] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Statuses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [StatusID] ASC
)
```

Comment: I think (not sure though) that SQL Server is quite limited when it comes to handling row locks. At some point it simply gives up and locks the whole table. Another difference could be the usage of snapshot isolation in one but not the other.

Comment: Is there an index on `TransactionID`?

Comment: Got to be a guess from here. But Use Sql Activity Monitor to see what sort of locks are being used. SQl server will promote row locks to page locksas part of optimisatioon, so if your newly inserted row is in the same page as the one you are trying to select. Saying that why isn't your insert transaction completing in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: The reason is that the insert is not alone in the transaction, it will do another insert later, it just waits for among other thing the select to complete.

Comment: Activity monitor show that the select is waiting for LCK_M_S.

Comment: Do an another insert later? How later? Transactions should be in and out, a dependency on an other transaction is not a good idea at all. Either  they should be in one transaction, or you time out and implement "Somone else is doing sumfin, try again later".

Comment: It will do it asap, it just need the answer from the select statement before it knows what to insert.
I know the current code is not perfect, LLBLGen that we use as ORM creates a lot of extra fluff which makes it hard to follow the code and also modify it. However, I would very much like not to do any code changes to make it run with this empty test database when it works fine in both dev and production.

Answer (score 0):

I did 1000 inserts into the table (of the same INSERT as in the question) and the problem went away. Not a perfect solution but apparently fixes the problem.